# Make body readonly

Tags: jquery, html, readonly

On opening a dialog I want to make the rest of the body readonly/unselectable. I'm using jquery.
Currently I'm using this, but it doesnt work:

```
<script>
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('#advertMenu').click(function() {
        $("body").attr("readonly", "readonly"); 
    });
});
</script>
```

After Edit

```
$("body").css("-moz-user-select", "-moz-none"); 
        $("body").css("-khtml-user-select", "none");
        $("body").css("-webkit-user-select", "none");
        $("body").css("-o-user-select", "none");
        $("body").css("-user-select", "none");
```

Comment: What type of dialog? jQuery dialog? In this case you can open like modal. [jQuery modal dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal)

Comment: no, I'll prompt a div & make the rest body's opacity low & want to make it uneditable.

Comment: it means you want to display some kind of overlay on screen, right?

Comment: Try use jQuery dialog instead. Is very good and probably remove all your problems and use have a lot of more usages. But if you don't want change your code use can put a `div` hover all other elements with the opacity that you want (overlay div).

Comment: @muneebShabbir ... yes !!

Comment: @JorgeLoureiro .... using jquery increses the load time of the page, Thats why i avoid it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $('body').attr('unselectable', 'on')
             .css('user-select', 'none')
             .on('selectstart', false);
             });
```

**Live Demo:**http://jsfiddle.net/d48vY/

Comment: yes it works, but the problem is all the links & from fields are still selectable. how can they be disabled as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
.unselectable {
    -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

 $('#advertMenu').click(function() {
        $("body").addClass('unselectable'); 
 });
```

Comment: When it will be reverted back?

Comment: yeah. ive tried your latest one with "class" , dindt get a positive result /